# How to make VC compiler optimize my code with SIMD better?

Tags: visual-c++, optimization, sse, simd

I'm now learning SIMD and thinking about how to let compiler optimize my code better. Now I'm playing with Visual C++ 2013 x86.

I have an array, I have another array, and I want to compute like this:

```
void computeSum(float* __restrict arr, float* __restrict inp1, float* __restrict inp2, int count)
{
    __declspec(align(16)) float* p1 = inp1;
    __declspec(align(16)) float* p2 = inp2;
    __declspec(align(16)) float* ret = arr;

    while (count > 0)
    {
        ret[0] = p1[0] + p2[0];
        ret[1] = p1[1] + p2[1];
        ret[2] = p1[2] + p2[2];
        ret[3] = p1[3] + p2[3];

        p1 += 4;
        p2 += 4;
        ret += 4;

        count -= 4;
    }
}
```

I want to tell the compiler that the arrays are aligned to 16-byte boundary and anyone is not overlay on another, and one loop will compute 4 continuous float number's summation.

But in generated code, VC prefer MOVSS/ADDSS and not use ADDPS which I hope it to.

If I configure the project to use LLVM-vs2013 tool chain, it use ADDPS to compute the summation.

I know how to use compiler intrinsics to write SIMD code, but that's not what I want.

Are there any more hints that VC needs to use ADDPS instruction?

This is the full piece of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void computeSum(float* __restrict arr, float* __restrict inp1, float* __restrict inp2, int count)
{
    __declspec(align(16)) float* p1 = inp1;
    __declspec(align(16)) float* p2 = inp2;
    __declspec(align(16)) float* ret = arr;

    while (count > 0)
    {
        ret[0] = p1[0] + p2[0];
        ret[1] = p1[1] + p2[1];
        ret[2] = p1[2] + p2[2];
        ret[3] = p1[3] + p2[3];

        p1 += 4;
        p2 += 4;
        ret += 4;

        count -= 4;
    }
}

int main()
{
    float* inp1 = (float*)_aligned_malloc(sizeof(float) * 128, 16);
    float* inp2 = (float*)_aligned_malloc(sizeof(float) * 128, 16);
    float* result = (float*)_aligned_malloc(sizeof(float) * 128, 16);

    for (int i = 0; i < 128; ++i)
    {
        inp1[i] = inp2[i] = i;
    }

    computeSum(result, inp1, inp2, 128);

    for (int i = 0; i < 128; ++i)
    {
        printf("%f\t", result[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you specify /arch:SSE (or similar)?

Comment: @harold yes, the switch /arch:SSE2 is enabled.

Comment: Did you try with *not* unrolling the loop ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust No, I haven't. Thank you for the advise. Now I tried it ( for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) ret[i]=p1[i]+p2[i]; ) but it didn't make difference.

Comment: Did you try a single loop ?

Comment: Sometimes OpenMP pragmas can also help.

Answer (score 2):

Visual C++ 2013 or later will default to use `/arch:SSE2` for x86, but you should still check the settings in your Visual Studio project to make sure it hasn't explicitly been set to something else. For x64, `/arch:SSE2` is implicit.

The only time that Visual C++ automatically generates multi-lane (like `ADDPS`) rather than single-lane (`ADDSS`) instructions is due to the auto-vectorizer. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh872235(v=vs.120).aspx) for details and pay particular attention to the `/Qvec-report:2` switch--and note that this will not happen with optimizations disabled as is common in Debug configurations.

Most SIMD (multi-lane) codegen is better accomplished with explicit intrinsics usage. For a lot of examples of this style of coding, see [DirectXMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath).

Comment: It's very important for me getting to know it's called "Auto-vectorizer" and the parameter switch to enable report. But after some trials I can't still make the optimizer use addps. Would you please give a piece of sample code? Thank you